# How to solve linear system of equations which have inequality constraints?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, least-squares, quadratic-programming

I have been trying to solve the below problem using least squares regression in python. However, my problem lies in adding the constraints. From what I can see from the implementation of least squares in python's scipy package, I can only declare constraints on the unknown variables (x). Linear programming seems to allow for inequality constraints, but I don't think this problem fits into linear programming due to the objective function being non-linear. Does anyone have any advice on how I could go about solving this?

$$
y = min_x \frac{1}{2}||Dx-d||_2^2  
$$
$$
s.t. 
$$
$$
Ax \leq c 
$$

Comment: Providing that $D$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, then the above minimization problem is convex. In that case you can you a variety of algorithms/solvers for it. Interior point methods are probably most suitable for what you need, and they are available in the CVXPY package. Refer to https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/least_squares.html

Comment: *quadratic programming*

Comment: As a possibly more efficiently computed alternative to methods mentioned in answers in the preceding comments, you can use a "linearly-constrained linear least squares" solver. They exist. For instance, lsqlin https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html in MATLAB

Answer (score 1):

It will strongly depend on how the problem is posed. Say, if $Ax \leq c$ is a compact region $R$, you can apply Weierstrass Theorem and optimize inside it with the Differential of $y$ and then comparing with the values of the border of the region, as usual. Of course this could mean a lot of work, depending on $R$.
If $R$ is not a compact region I would try to check the growth of $y$ along unbounded direction to get a glimpse of what's going on.

If $y$ were linear you have the simplest case since the optimization point lies in a vertex (or segment joining two vertices), but unfortunately this is not your case, as you probably already know according to your remark.

Cheers.